# Why isn't this Python pythagorean theorem solver working?

Tags: python, pythagorean

```
print "Welcome to Dylan's Pythagorean Theorem Solver."

from math import sqrt 

print "What are we solving for? A hypotenuse or a leg?"

ask = raw_input("# ")

if ask == "hypotenuse":
    print "What is the value of your first leg?"

    leg1 = raw_input("# ")

    print "The value of your first leg is %s. What is the value of your second leg?" % (leg1)

    leg2 = raw_input("# ")    

    print "The length of your hypotenuse is "sqrt((leg1 ** 2) + (leg2 ** 2))
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: You should note what error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a beginner but this is how I got your code to work:

Raw_input produces strings. You need to convert leg1 and leg2 to ints or floats before you can use them in sqrt. You can do that like this:

```
leg1 = int(input("# "))
```

You've got the same problem but in reverse in print (python is expecting a str but getting a float). You're also missing an operator in print.

It might be easier to just create a new variable for the result of sqrt, convert it to a str, and then use the variable in print.

```
hypotenuse = str(sqrt((leg1 ** 2) + (leg2 ** 2)))
```